# Material UI position Box element to bottom of parent

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Hello everyone I have the following structure:

```
  <Box width="100%" height="100%" p={1}>
       <Box my={1} display="flex" justifyContent="center">
                                  
       </Box>
       <Box color="text.disabled">
                               
       </Box>
       <Box mt={3}>
         position at bottom
       </Box>
 </Box>
```

I am trying to fix the bottom box to the bottom of its parent. So far I have tried:

`marginTop: "auto"`
`bottom: 0`

And neither of them work.

Comment: How did you solve?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a position="absolute" box.Here are some good examples: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp
Important is that the parent box is also positioned. Here is your code expanded:

```
<Box width="100%" height="100%" p={1} position="relative">
   <Box my={1} display="flex" justifyContent="center">
                              
   </Box>
   <Box color="text.disabled">
                           
   </Box>
   <Box mt={3} position="absolute" bottom="0px">
     position at bottom
   </Box>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using flexbox.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
}

#top {
  background-color: salmon;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#middle {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  min-height: 100px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#bottom {
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='top'></div>
  <div id='middle'></div>
  <div id='bottom'></div>
</div>
```